# How to return object that called a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me out with the code below:

```
function returnObj(){return this}

a = {
   name: "Eva",
   age: "12",
   getContext: returnObj
}
a.getContext // logs Object{name:"Eva", ...} which is fine.
```

But when I try

```
a = {
   name: "Eva",
   age: "12",
   getContext: function(){
      returnObj();
   }
}
a.getContext // logs undefined.
```

Can someone please help me understand what is going on here, and show me how I can make the 2nd piece of code return the object that called the function when I call `a.getContext()` just like the 1st one did.

Comment: `returnObj.call(this);`.

Comment: This is solved with a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) ([How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)) no the [function context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).  

    var a = (function () {
      var obj = {
            name: "Eva",
            age: "12",
            getContext: function () { 
               return obj;
            }
          };
      return obj;
    })();
    console.log(`getContext().name: ${a.getContext().name}`);

Comment: *return the object that called the function*. JavaScript had [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee) but that has been removed for ES5 strict mode.

Comment: ... and the obsolete [`arguments.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/caller).